# What is the correct verb in this case?

Tags: verb-usage

I said this sentence:

> Es ist ein Leben, das über seinen Zweck hinaus gelebt **hat**.

and was corrected to this:

> Es ist ein Leben, das über seinen Zweck hinaus gelebt **wird**.

And I do not see the need for the correction. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider who's doing the living, so to speak ;)

> Es ist ein Leben, das über seinen Zweck hinaus gelebt hat.

would translate to something like

> It is a life that has lived beyond its purpose.

But you probably want to say something like

> It is a life that *is* lived beyond its purpose.
> Es ist ein Leben, das über seinen Zweck hinaus gelebt *wird*.

The life isn't living itself, it is lived by a living being (for example, a human).

Comment: Yes, I see your point. But considering that this pertains to a literary context, in which poetic latitude is found, I can see how both meanings would have their uses.